# Iterate through folders and check if a certain file exists

Tags: file, powershell, loops, directory, exists

I was asked the following: Iterate through a list of folders, then iterate through a list of subfolders and finally check if there's a file named "can_erase.txt" on each subfolder. If the file exists, I must read it, save a parameter and delete the respective folder (not the main folder, but the subfolder which contains the file).

I started by using a `for` loop, but the names of the folders are random and I reached a dead end, so I thought I could use a `foreach`. Can anyone help me?

EDIT: My code is still pretty basic, since I know the names of the parent folders (they're named *stream1*, *stream2*, *stream3* and *stream4*) but their subfolders are randomly named.

My current code:

```
For ($i=1; $i -le 4; $i++)
{
    cd "stream$i"
    Get-ChildItem -Recurse  | ForEach (I don't know which parameters I should use)
    {
        #check if a certain file exists and read it
        #delete folder if the file was present
    }
        cd ..
}
```

Comment: Please *show* us what you have tried (i.e. your code) and explain how the actual behavior was different from what you expected. We're here to help, but you need to give us something to help you with first. We're not going to write the code for you.

Comment: Thanks @AnsgarWiechers, I've attached the code in the original post. Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this situation, you'll need multiple loops to get the stream folders, get those subfolders, then parse through all the files in the subfolders.

```
foreach ($folder in (Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\streamscontainerfolder' -Directory)) {
    foreach ($subFolder in (Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Directory)) {
        if ('filename' -in (Get-ChildItem -Path $subFolder -File).Name) {
            Remove-Item -Path $subFolder -Recurse -Force
            continue
        }
    }
}
```

The alternative to this is using the pipeline:

```
# This gets stream1, stream2, etc. added a filter to be safe in a situation where
# stream folders aren't the only folders in that directory
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\streamsContainerFolder -Directory -Filter stream* |
    # This grabs subfolders from the previous command
    Get-ChildItem -Directory |
        # Finally we parse the subfolders for the file you're detecting
        Where-Object { (Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -File).Name -contains 'can_erase.txt' } |
        ForEach-Object {
            Get-Content -Path "$($_.FullName)\can_erase.txt" |
                Stop-Process -Id { [int32]$_ } -Force # implicit foreach
            Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName -Recurse -Force
        }
```

As a default, I'd recommend using `-WhatIf` as a parameter to `Remove-Item` so you can see what it *would* do.

---

Bonus after more thinking:

```
$foldersToDelete = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Streams -Directory | Get-ChildItem -Directory |
    Where-Object { (Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -File).Name -contains 'can_erase.txt' }
foreach ($folder in $foldersToDelete) {
    # do what you need to do
}
```

Documentation:

- [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-5.1)
- [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/ForEach-Object?view=powershell-5.1)
- [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Where-Object?view=powershell-5.1)
- [`Remove-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Remove-Item?view=powershell-5.1)
- [`about_Continue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_continue?view=powershell-5.1)
- [`about_ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-5.1)
- [`about_Comparison_Operators`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-5.1)
- [`System.IO.FileSystemInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: The variable names `$folder/$subfolder` doesn't keep gci from iterating also files.

Comment: @LotPings You're correct.  In my alternative I used the proper switches, but it was still a WIP

Comment: Couldn't keep up with your rapid changes ;-)

Comment: @LotPings Fail fast!

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 thank you so much, I'm new to Powershell and your answer really enlightened me. 
Cheers!

Comment: @madsantos Glad to be of service. If this solved your question, kindly mark it as the answer ✅

Comment: Done :) Just one quick question, once you find that the .txt file is indeed inside the subfolders, how can you read it? I tried the `Get-Content` but I don't know how to write the path to the file.

Comment: @madsantos Which variant are you using?  If it's the last one, you'd need to do something like: `Get-ChildItem -Path $folder.FullName -Filter can_erase.txt | Get-Content`

Comment: @madsantos Although more simply: `Get-Content -Path "$folder\can_erase.txt"`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 it was indeed the alternative as I felt the piping was more intuitive :) I used the code you provided and placed it inside the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet.
What I expected: The program would read each file named can_erase.txt. I even added a `Write-Host "can_erase was found in $_"` so I could know where was the file found.
What happened: If there's more than one can_erase.txt file placed inside different folders, the program will only read the first it finds. Instead of multiple "can_erase was found in _path_", followed by each file contents, I can only find and read one file.

Comment: @madsantos So your folders can have multiple `can_erase` patterns found?  If that's the case, remove the `continue` statement

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 that was embarrassing. I completely missed the `continue`. To be totally clear, every subfolder which has a can_erase.txt inside it, must be deleted. Inside each text file there's a series of PID's which are used to kill a certain service. The event chronology would be something like this: Go to every _stream_ folder; check every subfolder; if there's a can_erase.txt file inside, read it and kill the service using the PID's inside; delete the folder where can_erase.txt was found. So indeed, there's more than one text file. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @madsantos Check out my edit for the pipeline variant.

Comment: I'm starting to understand the whole process, but there's one thing I still can't get. When you define the `Path` in `Get-Content`, the program will try to open a file which starts by the folder name, not the full path. So it's giving me an error (it says it can't open a file in C:\Users\Desktop\folder where the txt was found\can_erase.txt. I saved the script in my Desktop). That was one of my fears once I realized I couldn't use a simple `for`, actually. I don't know how to pick the full path to the file, using pipes.

Comment: @madsantos To access the fullname property, you can use a subexpression: `-Path "$($_.FullName)\can_erase.txt"` although the string operator should do that by default, this is an explicit syntax.

Comment: Got it! Hopefully other newbies can learn from this thread as much as I did today.